# Crash -[CTTelephonyNetworkInfo updateRat:descriptor:]

Tags: ios, swift

Recently my Crashlytics & Apple crash logs received many crashes with `-[CTTelephonyNetworkInfo updateRat:descriptor:]` crash without much other information.

iOS 15 spuriously not encounter this issue so far.

`[CTTelephonyNetworkInfo connectionStateChanged:connection:dataConnectionStatusInfo:]` seems like related to network status switch, any idea or anyone encounter similar issues on your side?

```
Incident Identifier: BBE5C5D0-CCFC-4844-959B-35251E747380
Hardware Model:      iPhone11,8
Process:             MyApp [51043]
Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/6039F755-4C6D-4CB8-8CE2-D0F77763622B/MyApp.app/MyApp
Identifier:          com.myapp.fake.row
Version:             3 (6.1.4)
AppStoreTools:       13A227
AppVariant:          1:iPhone11,8:13
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Role:                unknown
Parent Process:      launchd [1]
Coalition:           com.myapp.fake.row [858]


Date/Time:           2021-10-13 16:52:41.5984 +0800
Launch Time:         2021-10-12 18:02:45.3682 +0800
OS Version:          iPhone OS 14.7.1 (18G82)
Release Type:        User
Baseband Version:    3.04.01
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x000000046021dd60
VM Region Info: 0x46021dd60 is not in any region.  Bytes after previous region: 7518412129  Bytes before following region: 48853033632
      REGION TYPE                 START - END      [ VSIZE] PRT/MAX SHRMOD  REGION DETAIL
      MALLOC_NANO              280000000-2a0000000 [512.0M] rw-/rwx SM=COW  
--->  GAP OF 0xd20000000 BYTES
      commpage (reserved)      fc0000000-1000000000 [  1.0G] ---/--- SM=NUL  ...(unallocated)

Termination Signal: Segmentation fault: 11
Termination Reason: Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0xb
Terminating Process: exc handler [51043]
Triggered by Thread:  17

Thread 0 name:
Thread 0:
0   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001a8644810 WTF::AtomStringImpl::remove(WTF::AtomStringImpl*) + 616 (HashTable.h:1329)
1   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001a8644840 WTF::AtomStringImpl::remove(WTF::AtomStringImpl*) + 664 (HashTable.h:1056)
2   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001a8689498 WTF::StringImpl::~StringImpl() + 76 (StringImpl.cpp:118)
3   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001a8689634 WTF::StringImpl::destroy(WTF::StringImpl*) + 24 (StringImpl.cpp:108)
4   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001a823a468 JSC::BuiltinNames::~BuiltinNames() + 5096 (StringImpl.h:1118)
5   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001a82205a0 JSC::CommonIdentifiers::~CommonIdentifiers() + 13024 (BuiltinNames.h:193)
6   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001a841648c JSC::VM::~VM() + 404 (VM.cpp:647)
7   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001a83078dc JSC::JSLockHolder::~JSLockHolder() + 244 (ThreadSafeRefCounted.h:117)
8   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001a7a0ace8 JSContextGroupRelease + 60 (JSContextRef.cpp:85)
9   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001a771f8c8 -[JSVirtualMachine dealloc] + 32 (JSVirtualMachine.mm:128)
10  JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001a771f868 -[JSContext dealloc] + 88 (JSContext.mm:97)
11  JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001a8683b40 WTF::RunLoop::TimerBase::start(WTF::Seconds, bool)::$_1::__invoke(__CFRunLoopTimer*, void*) + 76 (RunLoopCF.cpp:126)
12  CoreFoundation                  0x000000019e27d1d4 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 32 (CFRunLoop.c:1807)
13  CoreFoundation                  0x000000019e27cdd0 __CFRunLoopDoTimer + 1076 (CFRunLoop.c:2415)
14  CoreFoundation                  0x000000019e27c220 __CFRunLoopDoTimers + 328 (CFRunLoop.c:2575)
15  CoreFoundation                  0x000000019e275f8c __CFRunLoopRun + 1872 (CFRunLoop.c:3080)
16  CoreFoundation                  0x000000019e275308 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 600 (CFRunLoop.c:3242)
17  GraphicsServices                0x00000001b58f8734 GSEventRunModal + 164 (GSEvent.c:2259)
18  UIKitCore                       0x00000001a0cf375c -[UIApplication _run] + 1072 (UIApplication.m:3269)
19  UIKitCore                       0x00000001a0cf8fcc UIApplicationMain + 168 (UIApplication.m:4740)
20  MyApp       0x0000000104617380 main + 68 (GlobalTheme.swift:21)
21  libdyld.dylib                   0x000000019df31cf8 start + 4

Thread 1 name:
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001cc4c84fc mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001cc4c7884 mach_msg + 76 (mach_msg.c:103)
2   CoreFoundation                  0x000000019e27be58 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 372 (CFRunLoop.c:2641)
3   CoreFoundation                  0x000000019e275cf8 __CFRunLoopRun + 1212 (CFRunLoop.c:2974)
4   CoreFoundation                  0x000000019e275308 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 600 (CFRunLoop.c:3242)
5   Foundation                      0x000000019f564d8c -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 232 (NSRunLoop.m:377)
6   Foundation                      0x000000019f564c58 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runUntilDate:] + 92 (NSRunLoop.m:424)
7   UIKitCore                       0x00000001a0da8304 -[UIEventFetcher threadMain] + 516 (UIEventFetcher.m:929)
8   Foundation                      0x000000019f6d630c __NSThread__start__ + 864 (NSThread.m:724)
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001e9f70bfc _pthread_start + 320 (pthread.c:887)
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001e9f79758 thread_start + 8

Thread 2 name:
Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001cc4f0598 write + 8
1   FirebaseCrashlytics             0x00000001051faf04 FIRCLSSDKFileLog + 316 (FIRCLSInternalLogging.c:0)
2   FirebaseCrashlytics             0x00000001051fcd50 FIRCLSMachExceptionReply + 128 (FIRCLSMachException.c:267)
3   FirebaseCrashlytics             0x00000001051fcd50 FIRCLSMachExceptionServer + 992 (FIRCLSMachException.c:178)
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001e9f70bfc _pthread_start + 320 (pthread.c:887)
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001e9f79758 thread_start + 8

Thread 3 name:
Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001cc4ed0cc __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001e9f74460 _pthread_cond_wait + 1292 (pthread_cond.c:640)
2   ComScore                        0x0000000105040504 0x104fb0000 + 591108
3   ComScore                        0x0000000104fffbac 0x104fb0000 + 326572
4   ComScore                        0x0000000105040dcc 0x104fb0000 + 593356
5   ComScore                        0x0000000105044b2c 0x104fb0000 + 609068
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001e9f70bfc _pthread_start + 320 (pthread.c:887)
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001e9f79758 thread_start + 8

Thread 4 name:
Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001cc4ed0cc __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001e9f74460 _pthread_cond_wait + 1292 (pthread_cond.c:640)
2   ComScore                        0x0000000105040504 0x104fb0000 + 591108
3   ComScore                        0x0000000104fffbac 0x104fb0000 + 326572
4   ComScore                        0x0000000105040dcc 0x104fb0000 + 593356
5   ComScore                        0x0000000105044b2c 0x104fb0000 + 609068
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001e9f70bfc _pthread_start + 320 (pthread.c:887)
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001e9f79758 thread_start + 8

Thread 5 name:
Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001cc4c84fc mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001cc4c7884 mach_msg + 76 (mach_msg.c:103)
2   CoreFoundation                  0x000000019e27be58 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 372 (CFRunLoop.c:2641)
3   CoreFoundation                  0x000000019e275cf8 __CFRunLoopRun + 1212 (CFRunLoop.c:2974)
4   CoreFoundation                  0x000000019e275308 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 600 (CFRunLoop.c:3242)
5   CFNetwork                       0x000000019eb53b38 +[__CFN_CoreSchedulingSetRunnable _run:] + 568 (CoreSchedulingSet.mm:1374)
6   Foundation                      0x000000019f6d630c __NSThread__start__ + 864 (NSThread.m:724)
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001e9f70bfc _pthread_start + 320 (pthread.c:887)
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001e9f79758 thread_start + 8

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001cc4ed0cc __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001e9f74434 _pthread_cond_wait + 1248 (pthread_cond.c:636)
2   libc++.1.dylib                  0x00000001b2e87efc std::__1::condition_variable::wait(std::__1::unique_lock<std::__1::mutex>&) + 28 (__threading_support:428)
3   NewRelic                        0x00000001057289a8 0x1056a8000 + 526760
4   NewRelic                        0x0000000105728f7c 0x1056a8000 + 528252
5   NewRelic                        0x000000010572911c 0x1056a8000 + 528668
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001e9f70bfc _pthread_start + 320 (pthread.c:887)
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001e9f79758 thread_start + 8

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001cc4ed0cc __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001e9f74434 _pthread_cond_wait + 1248 (pthread_cond.c:636)
2   libc++.1.dylib                  0x00000001b2e87efc std::__1::condition_variable::wait(std::__1::unique_lock<std::__1::mutex>&) + 28 (__threading_support:428)
3   NewRelic                        0x00000001057289a8 0x1056a8000 + 526760
4   NewRelic                        0x0000000105728f7c 0x1056a8000 + 528252
5   NewRelic                        0x000000010572911c 0x1056a8000 + 528668
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001e9f70bfc _pthread_start + 320 (pthread.c:887)
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001e9f79758 thread_start + 8

Thread 8 name:
Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001cc4ed0cc __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001e9f74434 _pthread_cond_wait + 1248 (pthread_cond.c:636)
2   libc++.1.dylib                  0x00000001b2e87f98 std::__1::condition_variable::__do_timed_wait(std::__1::unique_lock<std::__1::mutex>&, std::__1::chrono::time_point<std::__1::chrono::system_clock, std::__1::chrono::duration<long long, std::__1::r... + 100 (__threading_support:434)
3   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001a86f5118 bmalloc::Scavenger::threadRunLoop() + 552 (__mutex_base:0)
4   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001a86f4bcc bmalloc::Scavenger::threadEntryPoint(bmalloc::Scavenger*) + 16 (Scavenger.cpp:395)
5   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001a86f60e4 void* std::__1::__thread_proxy<std::__1::tuple<std::__1::unique_ptr<std::__1::__thread_struct, std::__1::default_delete<std::__1::__thread_struct> >, void (*)(bmalloc::Scavenger*), bmalloc::Scaveng... + 48 (type_traits:3747)
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001e9f70bfc _pthread_start + 320 (pthread.c:887)
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001e9f79758 thread_start + 8

Thread 9 name:
Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001cc4c84fc mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001cc4c7884 mach_msg + 76 (mach_msg.c:103)
2   CoreFoundation                  0x000000019e27be58 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 372 (CFRunLoop.c:2641)
3   CoreFoundation                  0x000000019e275cf8 __CFRunLoopRun + 1212 (CFRunLoop.c:2974)
4   CoreFoundation                  0x000000019e275308 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 600 (CFRunLoop.c:3242)
5   Foundation                      0x000000019f564d8c -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 232 (NSRunLoop.m:377)
6   FirebaseDatabase                0x0000000105297528 -[_FSRRunLoopThread main] + 252 (FSRWebSocket.m:1860)
7   Foundation                      0x000000019f6d630c __NSThread__start__ + 864 (NSThread.m:724)
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001e9f70bfc _pthread_start + 320 (pthread.c:887)
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001e9f79758 thread_start + 8

Thread 10 name:
Thread 10:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001cc4ed62c select$DARWIN_EXTSN + 8
1   CoreFoundation                  0x000000019e289034 __CFSocketManager + 624 (CFSocket.c:1343)
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001e9f70bfc _pthread_start + 320 (pthread.c:887)
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001e9f79758 thread_start + 8

Thread 11 name:
Thread 11:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001cc4ef150 kevent + 8
1   Realm                           0x000000010585a720 realm::_impl::ExternalCommitHelper::listen() + 160 (external_commit_helper.cpp:216)
2   Realm                           0x000000010585b1ec operator() + 4 (external_commit_helper.cpp:173)
3   Realm                           0x000000010585b1ec __invoke<(lambda at /MyApp/Pods/Realm/Realm/ObjectStore/src/impl/apple/external_commit_helper.cpp:171:28)> + 4 (type_traits:3747)
4   Realm                           0x000000010585b1ec __thread_execute<std::__1::unique_ptr<std::__1::__thread_struct>, (lambda at /MyApp/Pods/Realm/Realm/ObjectStore/src/impl/apple/external_commit_helper.cpp:... + 4 (thread:280)
5   Realm                           0x000000010585b1ec void* std::__1::__thread_proxy<std::__1::tuple<std::__1::unique_ptr<std::__1::__thread_struct, std::__1::default_delete<std::__1::__thread_struct> >, realm::_impl::ExternalCommitHelper::ExternalCom... + 52 (thread:291)
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001e9f70bfc _pthread_start + 320 (pthread.c:887)
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001e9f79758 thread_start + 8

Thread 12 name:
Thread 12:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001cc4c84fc mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001cc4c7884 mach_msg + 76 (mach_msg.c:103)
2   CoreFoundation                  0x000000019e27be58 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 372 (CFRunLoop.c:2641)
3   CoreFoundation                  0x000000019e275cf8 __CFRunLoopRun + 1212 (CFRunLoop.c:2974)
4   CoreFoundation                  0x000000019e275308 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 600 (CFRunLoop.c:3242)
5   AudioSession                    0x00000001a5d24f20 GenericRunLoopThread::Entry(void*) + 164 (GenericRunLoopThread.h:91)
6   AudioSession                    0x00000001a5d270d8 CAPThread::Entry(CAPThread*) + 92 (CAPThread.cpp:321)
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001e9f70bfc _pthread_start + 320 (pthread.c:887)
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001e9f79758 thread_start + 8

Thread 13 name:
Thread 13:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001cc4c84fc mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001cc4c7884 mach_msg + 76 (mach_msg.c:103)
2   CoreFoundation                  0x000000019e27be58 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 372 (CFRunLoop.c:2641)
3   CoreFoundation                  0x000000019e275cf8 __CFRunLoopRun + 1212 (CFRunLoop.c:2974)
4   CoreFoundation                  0x000000019e275308 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 600 (CFRunLoop.c:3242)
5   Foundation                      0x000000019f564d8c -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 232 (NSRunLoop.m:377)
6   Foundation                      0x000000019f59843c -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) run] + 92 (NSRunLoop.m:402)
7   MyApp       0x00000001047be170 +[GAI threadMain:] + 64
8   Foundation                      0x000000019f6d630c __NSThread__start__ + 864 (NSThread.m:724)
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001e9f70bfc _pthread_start + 320 (pthread.c:887)
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001e9f79758 thread_start + 8

Thread 14:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001e9f79744 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 15:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001e9f79744 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 16:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001e9f79744 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 17 name:
Thread 17 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00000001b2e09dd0 objc_release + 16 (objc-runtime-new.h:1589)
1   CoreTelephony                   0x000000019e8686e8 -[CTTelephonyNetworkInfo updateRat:descriptor:] + 556 (CTTelephonyNetworkInfo.mm:671)
2   CoreTelephony                   0x000000019e868430 -[CTTelephonyNetworkInfo queryRatForDescriptor:] + 164 (CTTelephonyNetworkInfo.mm:636)
3   CoreTelephony                   0x000000019e8671b8 -[CTTelephonyNetworkInfo connectionStateChanged:connection:dataConnectionStatusInfo:] + 72 (CTTelephonyNetworkInfo.mm:471)
4   CoreFoundation                  0x000000019e307724 __invoking___ + 148
5   CoreFoundation                  0x000000019e1dad04 -[NSInvocation invoke] + 380 (NSForwarding.m:3448)
6   CoreFoundation                  0x000000019e1db308 -[NSInvocation invokeWithTarget:] + 80 (NSForwarding.m:3549)
7   CoreTelephony                   0x000000019e8712cc void dispatch::async<-[CoreTelephonyClientMux sink:handleNotification:]::$_2>(dispatch_queue_s*, std::__1::unique_ptr<-[CoreTelephonyClientMux sink:handleNotification:]::$_2, std::__1::default_dele... + 44 (CoreTelephonyClientMux.mm:238)
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000019deef81c _dispatch_client_callout + 20 (object.m:559)
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000019def7004 _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 620 (inline_internal.h:2557)
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000019def7c00 _dispatch_lane_invoke + 404 (queue.c:3862)
11  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000019df024bc _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 764 (queue.c:6589)
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001e9f727a4 _pthread_wqthread + 276 (pthread.c:2437)
13  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001e9f7974c start_wqthread + 8

Thread 18:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001e9f79744 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 19:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001e9f79744 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 20 name:
Thread 20:
0   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000019df17bfc firehose_drain_notifications_once + 0 (firehose_buffer.c:424)
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000019df17798 firehose_buffer_tracepoint_reserve_slow + 52 (firehose_buffer.c:1348)
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000019df1615c voucher_activity_trace_v_2 + 988 (firehose_inline_internal.h:390)
3   libsystem_trace.dylib           0x00000001b4b59864 _os_log_impl_flatten_and_send + 5592 (log.c:1866)
4   libnetwork.dylib                0x000000019f2441f4 nw_connection_endpoint_report_on_nw_queue + 7888 (connection.m:0)
5   libnetwork.dylib                0x000000019eeb9578 nw_endpoint_handler_report + 304 (endpoint_handler.m:0)
6   libnetwork.dylib                0x000000019f2222a8 nw_endpoint_resolver_receive_report + 3060 (endpoint_resolver.m:0)
7   libnetwork.dylib                0x000000019eeb9578 nw_endpoint_handler_report + 304 (endpoint_handler.m:0)
8   libnetwork.dylib                0x000000019eebebd8 nw_endpoint_handler_path_change + 1392 (endpoint_handler.m:871)
9   libnetwork.dylib                0x000000019eebd0a8 __nw_endpoint_handler_initialize_association_block_invoke + 156 (endpoint_handler.m:898)
10  libnetwork.dylib                0x000000019f0677d8 __nw_association_update_paths_block_invoke.81 + 92 (association.m:316)
11  libnetwork.dylib                0x000000019f217828 nw_hash_table_apply + 124 (hash_table.c:381)
12  libnetwork.dylib                0x000000019f0670ec nw_association_update_paths + 488 (association.m:311)
13  libnetwork.dylib                0x000000019f373e3c nw_path_necp_update_evaluator + 2092 (path_evaluation.m:996)
14  libnetwork.dylib                0x000000019f3732e4 nw_path_necp_check_for_updates + 1028 (path_evaluation.m:1084)
15  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000019deef81c _dispatch_client_callout + 20 (object.m:559)
16  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000019def2cf4 _dispatch_continuation_pop + 448 (inline_internal.h:2557)
17  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000019df054b8 _dispatch_source_invoke + 1284 (source.c:570)
18  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000019def8ee8 _dispatch_workloop_invoke + 1680 (inline_internal.h:2598)
19  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000019df024bc _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 764 (queue.c:6589)
20  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001e9f727a4 _pthread_wqthread + 276 (pthread.c:2437)
21  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001e9f7974c start_wqthread + 8

Thread 21:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001e9f79744 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 17 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x00000002831bdd40   x1: 0x00000001ed675455   x2: 0x0000000000000002   x3: 0x00000001ad962188
    x4: 0x00000000000062dc   x5: 0x0000000000000001   x6: 0x3130303030303030   x7: 0x0000000000000000
    x8: 0x0000dbc46021dd40   x9: 0x000000046021dd40  x10: 0x000000070000078c  x11: 0x00ff0001071d5400
   x12: 0x00000000000000fd  x13: 0x00000001071d63c0  x14: 0x00000000cce5e000  x15: 0x00000002009a1b80
   x16: 0x00000001b2e09dc0  x17: 0xed017f019e1eb8b8  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x00000002831de250
   x20: 0x0000000283898de0  x21: 0x00000002831bdd40  x22: 0x0000000281b951a0  x23: 0x00000002831de4c0
   x24: 0x000000028389ea20  x25: 0x00000002831de4c0  x26: 0x00000002831de4c0  x27: 0x0000000000000000
   x28: 0x0000000000000104   fp: 0x000000016bbbe7d0   lr: 0x000000019e8686e8
    sp: 0x000000016bbbe790   pc: 0x00000001b2e09dd0 cpsr: 0x20000000
   esr: 0x92000006 (Data Abort) byte read Translation fault
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: You'd better paste the full crash stack including metadata out.

Comment: @Itachi thanks, updated with full crash stack

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that it crashed whilst doing a release from an asynchronous callback.  That normally means that the object lifetime is incorrectly managed.  That is perhaps because the original object was not properly retained, and so when it was released, it was double-released.  I noticed that the problem comes via C++ code (the .mm file in the crash); the standard template library has its own clean-up lifecycle and the mix of Objective-C with C++ can be a road to tripping up on these subtle issues.

I suggest you run your code with memory diagnostics enabled.  First go with detecting for Zombie objects.  `Project->Scheme->Edit Scheme`; Select Diagnostics Tab; `Memory Management->Zombie Objects`.

You ask for an answer from a reputable source; I've published a book "iOS Crash Dump Analysis" that demonstrates how mixing C++ and Objective-C can lead to issues such as these.